# Setting BaseFont parameters back to default after bold

Tags: itext

I am using absolute positioning when writing text in a PDF document using iTextSharp. It can only deal with BaseFont and it is not possible to set a **Bold** decoration on a base font.

I read in a post that this was the way to set the font to bold:

```
 pdfContentByte.SetCharacterSpacing(1);
 pdfContentByte.SetRGBColorFill(66, 00, 00);  
 pdfContentByte.SetLineWidth((float)0.5);                   
 pdfContentByte.SetTextRenderingMode(PdfContentByte.TEXT_RENDER_MODE_FILL_STROKE);
```

That worked but created a another problem. I don't know how to set these parameters back to my old default (none-bolded font).

Do you know how?

TIA
Søren D.

Comment: I created two fonts to deal with this issue.  The first was normal font, the other in bold.  I know it's annoying but it seemed much easier than changing the font back and forth when needed (I reused both repeatedly).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

the answer is very simple: you need to *save* the state before you change it, and *restore* the state after you've added the text:

```
pdfContentByte.SaveState();
pdfContentByte.SetCharacterSpacing(1);
pdfContentByte.SetRGBColorFill(66, 00, 00);  
pdfContentByte.SetLineWidth((float)0.5);                   
pdfContentByte.SetTextRenderingMode(PdfContentByte.TEXT_RENDER_MODE_FILL_STROKE);
// add the text using the changed state
pdfContentByte.RestoreState();
```

The changes you make to the character spacing, color, line width and rendering mode will only be valid between the `SaveState()` and `RestoreState()` sequence.