# Itextsharp problem stroke is applying to cell text

Tags: c#, pdf, itext

So I'm applying a canvas stroke to my pdf, but the stroke is applying to the cell text. But only the first cell.

[image: here is image]

Here is the method to draw the page border:

```
protected void DrawPageBorder(PdfWriter writer, Document document, PdfContentByte canvas)
    {
        var pageBorderRect = new Rectangle(document.PageSize);
        var content = writer.DirectContent;

        pageBorderRect.Left += document.LeftMargin - BorderDifference;
        pageBorderRect.Right -= document.RightMargin - BorderDifference;
        pageBorderRect.Top -= document.TopMargin - BorderDifference;
        pageBorderRect.Bottom += document.BottomMargin - BorderDifference;
        content.SetLineDash(3f, 3f);
        content.SetRGBColorStroke(236, 236, 236);
        //canvas.SetLineWidth(FillOpacity);
        //canvas.SetRGBColorStroke(0, 0, 0);
        //canvas.SetRGBColorStroke(236, 236, 236);
        //canvas.SetLineDash(3f, 3f);
        content.Rectangle(pageBorderRect.Left, pageBorderRect.Bottom, pageBorderRect.Width, pageBorderRect.Height);
        content.Stroke();
    }
```

this is the code which adds the pdf table  with the border:

```
var docTable = new PdfPTable(1);
docTable.WidthPercentage = 100f;

PdfContentByte canvas = new PdfContentByte(pdfWriter);
DrawPageBorder(pdfWriter, doc, canvas);
```

This is the code to add the first table cell:

```
titleFont.Size = 24.0f;
var text1 = new PdfPCell(new Phrase("To:", titleFont))
{
HorizontalAlignment = Element.ALIGN_LEFT,
Border = Rectangle.NO_BORDER,
PaddingTop = 20f,
PaddingLeft = 9f,
PaddingRight = 9f
};
docTable.AddCell(text1);
```

Anyone know where I'm going wrong here?

Thanks

Comment: Related: https://stackoverflow.com/q/23086454/1729265 (same underlying cause and solution).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Whenever you mix high level api content creating (like you do with the table) and low level api drawing (like you do in `DrawPageBorder`), make sure your low level code does not leave behind any change to graphics state parameters.

Your code leaves changes to the LineDash and the stroking color.

You can do so by wrapping your code drawing on `content` in a safe-graphics-state / restore-graphics-state envelop.

In your case:

```
    content.SaveState();
    content.SetLineDash(3f, 3f);
    content.SetRGBColorStroke(236, 236, 236);
    //canvas.SetLineWidth(FillOpacity);
    //canvas.SetRGBColorStroke(0, 0, 0);
    //canvas.SetRGBColorStroke(236, 236, 236);
    //canvas.SetLineDash(3f, 3f);
    content.Rectangle(pageBorderRect.Left, pageBorderRect.Bottom, pageBorderRect.Width, pageBorderRect.Height);
    content.Stroke();
    content.RestoreState();
```

Comment: Finally got the chance to come back to this project, works now and thanks for the clear explanation. Makes sense :)